# Can not install chrome browser in ubuntu 20.04 on Raspberry pi 4 8Gb

Tags: google-chrome

Installing with a command line or in the GUI gives both the same error message. Packages are only fot AMD64 architecture not for ARM64

I only can find a .deb file for the amd64 processor. How can i install chrome?

Comment: I suspect you'll have to ask Google to release it. Chrome was ready to go more than a year ago (on arm it was written), however google have opted to not release it (it's closed source code built on the open source `chromium` browser). You may need to use another browser until you've persuaded google to package it for arm64.

Comment: As guiverc mentioned, unless Google releases it, you cannot. Firefox works just fine. If you "need" the same engine as chrome uses, you can install chromium with `sudo snap install chromium`

Answer (score 2):

Chrome is only compiled/distributed for x86 processors but you should be able to use the open source project, Chromium, that Chrome is based upon.  You can install it by doing `apt install -y chromium-browser`

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem a few days ago mate. Can't install Chrome on my Debian 10 Buster (official) after many .debs tryied.

With some research i reallized that built Debian it's Chromium and it's a Chrome substitute, so i ended up to give up

Answer (score 0):

You just said that you tried to install chrome from terminal. But, how can we know that which command you tried..? I actually install chrome by following steps.

```
sudo snap install chromium
```

There's another way to install chrome. Visit the [link](https://www.google.com/chrome/) and download chrome with extension .deb

```
cd Downloads
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Question clearly asks for solution to install Chrome on arm64 not amd64. You have given command to install amd64 package.